# Hp a1630N Pavillion dual monitor

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, hp-pavilion

I have a HP a 1630 desktop with the following:

- Windows XP - Service Pack 3
- GeForce 6150 LE integrated video card
- ASUS A8M2N-LA Motherboard – I have the most recent updated BIOS

I purchased a MSI 1GB NVidia GeForce 8400GS card.

I am trying to run dual monitors.

When I installed the card, I changed the set-up to PCI-e. The computer starts to boot but hangs at the Windows XP start-up screen. The three blue tabs just continue to scroll in the box.

I had a friend come over and we put the card into his desktop and it worked fine.

Does anyone have any help. I called HP and they confirmed all should be OK but they would charge me $49.00 for a possible diagnosis.

Comment: I know this is a late comment but.... Try uninstalling rhe drivers for the GeForce 6150, then shutdown, insert the new graphics board and boot. (and install the new drivers for this card after a successful boot).

Answer (score 0):

The card is likely not supported on Windows 98, that would be a problem.

If your on XP, then try running just the 8800 before putting in the new one. Also make sure you have the latest GeForce drivers.

Comment: I guess he *did* mean XP.

Comment: Oh, now that i reread it... Wonder where he got 98 from.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "running just the 8800" I have onboard 6150 and the new card is 8400.  I did update the motherboard bios and downloaded the latest drivers from NVidia.  Still it won't boot.  Starts and hangs on the XP screen with the three blue blocks scrolling in the box.